# googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: sheets version v4

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, pyinstaller

I'm working with Google Sheets API and Pyinstaller.

My code runs just fine on the IDE, but whenever i try to run it on a .exe created by Pyinstaller, it provides the following error:[image: error service].

I thought it could be a missing file or dependency but i tested it on other environments and the error persists. Any thoughts?

It was supposed to update a Google Sheets file and it does exactly that, except when i run it with pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1):

pyinstaller --onefile main.py --collect-data googleapiclient

Answer (score 0):

If you used --onedir (One Directory) this should work fine.

If you want a (One file) option then this issue didn't have any solution until now (I made a good search)

Comment: --onedir does not work as well... It returns the same error.

Comment: I find a fix for it and solve it, you should edit the library

Answer (score 0):

edit the file

> \Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery_cache_*init*_.py

**add this line after line 26:**

Old:

```
DISCOVERY_DOC_DIR = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "documents"
    )
```

New:

```
DISCOVERY_DOC_DIR = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "documents"
    )

IS_INSTALLER = getattr(sys, "frozen", False) and hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS")
if IS_INSTALLER:
    DISCOVERY_DOC_DIR = os.path.join(
        sys._MEIPASS, "documents"
    )
```